# Can't a method that receives an interface as a parameter in Android receive an object that implements the interface as a parameter?

Tags: java, android, interface, instance

Same as the question, A colleague of mine has implemented as below how to take an interface as a parameter to implement it abstractly as a library.

```
public void setData(
        List<ProgramGuideChannel> newChannels,
        Map<String, List<ProgramGuideSchedule<T>>> newChannelEntries,
        LocalDate selectedDate
) {
    programGuideManager.setData(newChannels, newChannelEntries, selectedDate, DISPLAY_TIMEZONE);
}
```

The problematic part here is the first parameter, List Of ProgramGuideChannel

```
public class EpgChannel implements ProgramGuideChannel {
private final Channel channel;

public EpgChannel(Channel channel) {
    this.channel = channel;
}

@Override
public String getId() {
    return String.valueOf(channel.getId());
}

@Override
public Spanned getName() {
    return new SpannedString(channel.getDisplayName());
}

@Override
public String getImageUrl() {
    return channel.getAppLinkPosterArtUri();
}
public String getOriginalNetworkId(){
    return String.valueOf(channel.getOriginalNetworkId());
}
```

}
Like the code above, my EpgChannel class implements the ProgramGuideChannel interface.
And when I insert the List for this EpgChannel as a parameter to the setData method, an error occurs

```
setData(java.util.List<com.jhh.epg.model.ProgramGuideChannel>, java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.util.List<com.jhh.epg.model.ProgramGuideSchedule<com.google.android.media.tv.companionlibrary.model.Program>>>, java.time.LocalDate) in com.jhh.epg.ProgramGuideFragment cannot be applied to (java.util.List<com.jhh.phoenixplayer2.livetv.epg.EpgChannel>, java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.util.List<com.jhh.epg.model.ProgramGuideSchedule<com.google.android.media.tv.companionlibrary.model.Program>>>, java.time.LocalDate)
```

I don't understand this error. My EpgChannel object obviously has an instance of ProgramGuideChannel. However, my method is not aware of this.
Does anyone know the reason for this?

ps - There was no problem when the corresponding setData was developed in kotlin. I am thinking that it may be a Java problem.